# How to print the values of the y-axis individually in scrapy shell?

Tags: python, scrapy

FYI, I am trying to get the values of the price individually at the y-axis that always have html id of `font-size` with `11pt`.

Url I am trying to access: [link](https://research.investors.com/StockResearch/Scripts/ibdChart/print.html?t=1634287038721&params=MS=0,RS=0,DGO=0,DisplayMS=1,DisplayHelp=1,DisplayDGO=0,LDB=0,DisplayLDB=1,symbol=mcb,type=daily)

Code:

```
scrapy shell "https://research.investors.com/StockResearch/Scripts/ibdChart/print.html?t=1634287038721&params=MS=0,RS=0,DGO=0,DisplayMS=1,DisplayHelp=1,DisplayDGO=0,LDB=0,DisplayLDB=1,symbol=mcb,type=daily"
```

Then I type in:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[@font-size='11pt']//*[name()='text']/text()").extract()
```

i) The second line of code returns invalid expression (xpath error).

ii) Besides that, I also noticed that after the first line of code, it returns:

> response <403
> https://research.investors.com/StockResearch/Scripts/ibdChart/print.htm
> l?t=1634287038721&params=MS=0,RS=1,DGO=0,DisplayMS=1,DisplayHelp=1,DisplayDGO=0,LDB=0,Display
> LDB=1,symbol=mcb,type=daily>

I am not sure what is the cause of this error. Is it because of the auto print screen pop-up when we visit the website?

Answer (score 0):

403 means that access page has been denied by server. You can use `response.body` to print received html in scrapy shell.

I think you may need add some header to avoid it, such as:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "https://research.investors.com/StockResearch/Scripts/ibdChart/print.html?t=1634287038721&params=MS=0,RS=0,DGO=0,DisplayMS=1,DisplayHelp=1,DisplayDGO=0,LDB=0,DisplayLDB=1,symbol=mcb,type=daily"
```

Comment: For your case, the html is not your target, it render by javascript, so you can not get info from xpath, but you can get json object directly.